# Multiple Regular Expression in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

**Here is my regular expression ...**

```
^ +|( +; +)| +$
```

**Here is the screenshot of Regex with the Test String**

[image: Regex and Test String]

I have used the screenshot to highlight spaces ....

**What I want to do is format the string like this**

```
Trimester 1;Trimester 2;Trimester 3
```

So I want to

1. Remove spaces from the beginning and ending of the string,
2. Remove spaces before and after the semi-colons.

Here is my custom analyser ...

```
"analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "semi_colon_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                },
                "comma_analyzer": {
                    "type": "pattern",
                    "pattern": ",",
                    "lowercase": false
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "pattern",
                    "pattern": "( +; +)",
                    "replacement": "$1;"
                }
            }

        }
```

This works in regex101.com, but does not work in Elastic.

Can someone please help on how to implement this Regex in ElasticSearch ?

Thanks

**Edit**

Output of _analyze?analyzer=semi_colon_analyzer

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Trimester",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "1",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "Trimester",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "2",
      "start_offset": 23,
      "end_offset": 24,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "Trimester",
      "start_offset": 26,
      "end_offset": 35,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "3",
      "start_offset": 36,
      "end_offset": 37,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [char_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html). Try this,

```
 {
 "analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
     "semi_colon_analyzer": {
        "char_filter": "my_char_filter",
        "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
        "filter" : "trim"
     },
     "comma_analyzer": {
        "type": "pattern",
        "pattern": ",",
        "lowercase": false
     }
  },
  "char_filter": {
     "my_char_filter": {
        "type": "pattern_replace",
        "pattern": "(\\s+;\\s+)",
        "replacement": ";"
     }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
     "my_tokenizer": {
        "type": "pattern",
        "pattern": ";"
     }
     }
   }
 }
```

If you analyze `Trimester  1    ;  Trimester 2` using above created analyzer, you will get :

```
{
 "tokens": [
  {
     "token": "Trimester  1",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 12,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
  },
  {
     "token": "trimester 2",
     "start_offset": 19,
     "end_offset": 33,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 1
       }
     ]
  }
```

Comment: ERROR: "reason": "Custom Analyzer [semi_colon_analyzer] failed to find tokenizer under name [someTokenizer]"

Comment: You need to specify name of your tokenizer. :P

Comment: This is my tokenizer:  `"tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "pattern",
                    "pattern": "( +; +)",
                    "replacement": "$1;"
                }` Are you saying I need to include this code somewhere ?

Comment: You will have to remove tokenizer and use char_filter instead, For now Specify `"tokenizer" : "standard"` for now

Comment: Strange error:  `"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to find analyzer [semi_colon_analyzer]"`

Comment: what are you exactly running. Use this `PUT pattern 
{"analysis":{"analyzer":{"semi_colon_analyzer":{"char_filter":"my_char_filter","tokenizer":"whitespace"},"comma_analyzer":{"type":"pattern","pattern":",","lowercase":false}},"char_filter":{"my_char_filter":{"type":"pattern_replace","pattern":"( +; +)","replacement":"$1;"}}}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145603/discussion-between-slyper-and-richa).

Comment: ok, Its working now, but its not producing output as I was expecting .... Please see above the output produced by _analyze?analyzer=semi_colon_analyzer

Comment: Like this ....    `"token": "Trimester 1"` And I have no control over the spaces .... There can be 0, 1, 2, 3 or more spaces so that's why the Regex .... Please see the screenshot I attached .... The blue/green highlighting is the space .....

Comment: Have edited my answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution with a little bit of tweaking to my original mapping ...

```
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": "1",
    "number_of_replicas": "0",
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "semi_colon_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
            },
            "comma_analyzer": {
                "type": "pattern",
                "pattern": ",",
                "lowercase": false
            }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer": {
                "type": "pattern",
                 "pattern": "^ +|( *; *)| +$",
                "replacement": "$1;"
            }
        }

    }
},
```